# Customize block quote color in VSCode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using [Nord theme](https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-visual-studio-code) in VScode. The block quotes in the markdown files look like this which is very illegible. How to change the text background?

[image]

I have tried the followings in User Settings but it not working:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // changes the markdown preview
    "editor.textBlockQuote.background": "#0000ff", // Property not allowed
    "[Nord]": {
        "textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // changes the markdown preview
    },
},
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // Property not allowed
    "editor.textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // Property not allowed
    "[Nord]": {
        "textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // Property not allowed 
        "editor.textBlockQuote.background": "#ff0000", // Property not allowed
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The editor colorization comes from a textmate grammar. To override this, you need to use the `textMateRules` section of [`editor.tokenColorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Nord]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "markup.quote.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#f0f"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The scope used here (`markup.quote.markdown`) is the textmate scope of markdown block quotes. You can use the `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command in VS Code to determine the target scope

Note that VS Code does not support setting the background color of text. This is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3429)

Answer (score 1):

I use **Slack Theme Aubergine Dark** and had to change:

```
   "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Slack Theme Aubergine Dark]": {
            "comments": "#ffa600",
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope":"markup.quote.markdown",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FF0000",
                        "fontStyle": "bold"
                    }
                }
            ]

        },

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this, works fine:

```
     "workbench.colorCustomizations": { 
       "textBlockQuote.background":"#95e0d6"
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]